# How to use kurento-media-server for audio only stream?

Tags: webrtc, kurento

I want to have only audio stream communication between peers , I changed the parts of kurento.utils.js to get only audio stream via getusermedia 
but it's not working
I used this example [node-hello-world](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node/tree/master/kurento-hello-world) example

```
WebRtcPeer.prototype.userMediaConstraints = {
    audio : true,
    video : {
        mandatory : {
            maxWidth : 640,
            maxFrameRate : 15,
            minFrameRate : 15
        }
    }
};
```

to

```js
WebRtcPeer.prototype.userMediaConstraints = {
    audio : true,
    video : false
};
```

is it possible use kurento service for only audio stream?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is indeed possible with Kurento. There are two ways of doing this, depending on the desired scope of the modification:

1. Per webrtc endpoint: when you process the SDP offer sent by the client, you get an SDP answer from KMS that you have to send back. After invoking the `processOffer` method call, you can tamper the SDP to remove all video parts. That way, your client will send back only audio.
2. Globally: You can edit `/etc/kurento/sdp_pattern.txt` file removing all video related parts, this will force SdpEndpoints (parent class of WebrtcEndpoint) to only use audio.

---

EDIT 1

The file `sdp_pattern.txt` is deprecated in KMS 6.1.0, so method 2 shouldn't be used.

---

EDIT 2

There was an issue with the kurento-utils library, and the client was not correctly setting the `OfferToReceiveAudio`. It was fixed some time ago, and you shouldn't need tampering the SDPs now.

Comment: So, what is the new solution after all the edits?  I'm trying mediaConstraints: {audio:true} and it just never connects in the hello-world example.

Comment: @DobesVandermeer `{audio : true, video : false}` should be working fine. Is it not working for you?

Comment: Actually I did get it working that way, I should create a pull request with my audio-only example.

Comment: @DobesVandermeer Well, there's already one [here](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java/blob/master/kurento-hello-world-recording/src/main/resources/static/js/index.js#L221)

Answer (score 1):

git origin: https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-js.git
git branch: 6.6.0

My solution is only changing `var offerVideo = true;` to `var offerVideo = false;` in `generateOffer` function of kurento-utils.js file.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to modify the options that you pass to the WebRtcPeer.

```
var options = {  
  onicecandidate: onIceCandidate,  
  iceServers: iceServers,  
  mediaConstraints: {  
    audio:true,  
    video:false  
  }  
}
```

Besides, in the kurento-utils.js, the mediaContraints is overidden by this line:

```
constraints.unshift(MEDIA_CONSTRAINTS);
```

So comment it.